# How to configure mail /etc file?

Tags: command-line, mail, gmail

I have a **Ubuntu 16.10** VM that I'm trying to configure to send mail from the shell with my gmail address via `crontab`.

Which `/etc` file do I need to amend and what options do I need to set?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to switch to postfix and then you can "relay" your email via your gmail SMTP.  (make sure you setup the less-secure apps setting(s) inside of google as well so it will allow the SMTP connection from your machine)

`apt-get update && apt-get install postfix mailutils`

`vi /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`

add this line:

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 username@gmail.com:password
```

`chmod 600 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`

`vi /etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

then encode your password

`postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`

then kick postfix

`systemctl restart postfix.service`